# Define custom module map file in cocoapods Podspec

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I made a custom `module map` file to handle the `libxml` import in a swift project. (`non-modular include` error)

It's working great if I do it manually, but `cocoapods` won't find / resolve the module when I try to `pod lint` a simple project containing an import from this custom module.

I tried `s.module_map = "module/module.modulemap"` along with

```rb
core.xcconfig = {
  'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2 $(SRCROOT)/module $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libresolv',
  'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '"-lxml2"',
  'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES' => 'YES',
  'ENABLE_BITCODE' => 'NO',
  "SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS" => "$(SRCROOT)/module"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by setting the `pod_target_xcconfig` property. The complete part looks like that :

```
s.preserve_path = 'module/module.modulemap'
s.module_map = 'module/module.modulemap'

core.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/mypod/module' }
core.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2 $(PODS_ROOT)/mypod/module' }
```

Comment: Hey, I got the non modular error. Can you explain a little bit what you did here? Thanks

Comment: It depend on with header you have a modular header. You can try to use the @import syntax if you have the error on a #import <> syntax. Here you create a module.modulemap file, in which you place the declaration of your module (in my case libxml). Then you add it to your build settings to allow Xcode to use it, and compile

Comment: Moving the libxml2 location from `pod_target_xcconfig` to `xcconfig` did the trick for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your `module.modulemap` file for completion? I tried `pod lint` with all possible variants of the samples above, but I cannot get it to succeed. Do you still have to link against `xml2` with `s.libraries = 'xml2'`?

Comment: @Loegic can you post the content of your .modulemap file?

Comment: @Cyrus, it was a long time ago, but I think that if you search under my other answer you'll find an example